# Out of Office reply Outlook2007

Tags: exchange-2007, microsoft-office-2007

We have an Exchange 2007 SP3 environment and I have a user who is using Outlook 2007 that wants to use the different OOO replies (inside/outside your organization). She has entered a different reply for each but when you sends test emails to her work account from an outside email, she gets the reply meant for people inside the organization. Anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening Outlook with the switch /cleanrules

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-outlook-2010-HP010354956.aspx

After that, recreate the different OOF replies.

Comment: Will this work with Outlook 2007? This article references Outlook 2010.

Comment: Yes, `/cleanrules` has been around for quite a while.